# Join Collection to table

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, collection, join

So, I have subscribers collection:

```
$subscribersCollection =  Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->getCollection();
```

I want to join customer collection to it by email, so I did next:

```
$subscribersCollection->getSelect()
     ->join(array('cus'=>'customer_entity'),'cus.email=main_table.subscriber_email');
```

But in this way I only join `customer_entity` table, but not all the customer collection.
I think about also join other customers tables. Is there any better way to join customer collection?

UPDATE:

I have tried

```
$customerCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection'); 
$customerCollection->getSelect()->join(array('cus'=>'newsletter_subscriber'),'cu‌​s.subscriber_email = e.email');
$customerCollection->getItems()
```

Now it work, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to kick yourself when I show you :-)

Create a customer collection instance and join the newsletter table on that.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use just `email` instead of `main_table.email`.

Comment: In UPDATE case main table is not newsletter_subscriber

Comment: Yes, you are right. Please see my updated answer.